# automatically banned IP addresses

Tags: monerod, ban

I have not banned any IP address manually but I notice with the command ̀`bans` that some IPs are banned:

> 76.3.101.16 banned for 86268 seconds
>
> 188.232.79.74 banned for 85817 seconds
>
> 188.234.251.88 banned for 86220 seconds

Where do these IP addresses come from?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the daemon automatically bans peers for a day or so if they try to connect with an out of date client (pre hardfork), or possibly if they're just on the wrong chain for some other reason.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot for the life of me find the original post, but this feature is meant to automatically ignore peers on old Monero versions. This autoban feature is enabled by default.